# "Numbering" equations inside array{l}

Tags: equations, labels

i have this situation:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
A
\xrightarrow{T4} \\
\\
B
\xrightarrow{S} \\
\\
C
\xrightarrow{T5} \\
\\
D
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Here i have reported a minimal example but `A B C D` contain `vmatrix`. **I want add a label** to the number of equation itself for each member of this chain (3.21a) (3.21b) etc.
 How should I do ?

EDIT

If i try the new settings  in another context:

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
A\\
B\\
C\\
D
\end{vmatrix} 
\xrightarrow{T4} \\
\\
\begin{vmatrix}
E\\
F\\
G\\
\end{vmatrix} 
\xrightarrow{S} \\
\\
\begin{vmatrix}
I\\
L\\
M\\
\end{vmatrix} 
\xrightarrow{T5} \\
\\
\begin{vmatrix}
A\\
B\\
CC\\
DDDDDDD
\end{vmatrix} 
{\xrightarrow{T456}} \\
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

the matrices are not aligned, it is not so good to see, as i said i can fix it using h space. Tell me.

**NOTE**: the arrows have to stay on the right

Comment: Just add `&` in front of `\xrightarrow`

Comment: in this way works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for `align` or `alignat` together with `subequations`. I provide right or left alignment for the matrices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
A\\
B\\
C\\
D
\end{vmatrix} 
&\xrightarrow{T4} \label{foo1} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
E\\
F\\
G\\
\end{vmatrix} 
&\xrightarrow{S} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
I\\
L\\
M\\
\end{vmatrix} 
&\xrightarrow{T5} \label{foo2} \\
\begin{vmatrix}
A\\
B\\
CC\\
DDDDDDD
\end{vmatrix} 
&\xrightarrow{T456} \label{foo3}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\begin{vmatrix}
A\\
B\\
C\\
D
\end{vmatrix} 
&&\xrightarrow{T4} \label{foo4} \\
&\begin{vmatrix}
E\\
F\\
G\\
\end{vmatrix} 
&&\xrightarrow{S} \\
&\begin{vmatrix}
I\\
L\\
M\\
\end{vmatrix} 
&&\xrightarrow{T5} \label{foo5} \\
&\begin{vmatrix}
A\\
B\\
CC\\
DDDDDDD
\end{vmatrix} 
&&\xrightarrow{T456} \label{foo6}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]